# What does gradient mean on a hermitian manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Given a hermitian manifold (M, g), and a smooth real function $f$ on it, the following quantity is well defined: $|\nabla f|^2 = g^{j \bar i} \partial_{j} f \partial_{\bar i} f$. This notation is so confusing, because we know that $\nabla f = df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial z^i} dz_{i} + \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z^i}} d\bar{z_{i}}$, and the norm of $df$ with respect to the given metric is certainly not the one given. I have also seen people using $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g = g^{i \bar j} \partial_{j} g \partial_{\bar i} f + g^{i \bar j} \partial_{j} f \partial_{\bar i} g$. What is really the meaning of this $\nabla$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the usual definition of the gradient $\nabla f \in \Gamma(TM)$ of $f \in C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb{R})$: for all tangent vector $X$ to $M$, $\langle \nabla f, X\rangle = df(X)$. By extending the metric and $df$ $\mathbb{C}$-linearly to $T_{\mathbb C} M$, the identity $\langle \nabla f, \cdot \rangle = df$ also holds on $T_{\mathbb C} M$. Then, one can show that
$$
\nabla f = g^{\bar{i}j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}^i} \frac{\partial }{\partial z^j} + g^{i \bar{j}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z^i} \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}^j}.
$$
Thus, the $(1,0)$-part $\nabla^{1,0}f$ is given by
$$
\nabla^{1,0} f = g^{\bar{i}j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}^i} \frac{\partial }{\partial z^j}.
$$
Using the Hermitian inner product on $T^{1,0}M$, we have
$$
\lvert \nabla^{1,0} f\rvert^2 = g^{i \bar{j}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z^i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}^j}.
$$
Also, a direct calculation shows that $\lvert \nabla f \rvert^2$ with respect to the Riemannian metric is twice of $\lvert \nabla^{1,0} f\rvert^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very well written answer. One more question, is it obvious from the coordinate expression that $|\nabla^{1, 0} f|^2 = 0$ would imply $\nabla^{1,0}f = 0$?

Comment: @Adam Just consider the positive-definiteness of the matrix $(g^{i \bar{j}})$.